# Powershell Filter value based on Select-String

Tags: powershell

I am new to Powershell script
I am using vmstat command and i am trying to filter values based on total memory and used memory.

I have done this way but i am not able to just filter value.

PS /home/ec2-user> $usedmem = vmstat -s | Select-String 'used memory'

PS /home/ec2-user> $usedmem

```
   217976 K used memory
```

But my question is,

how can i just get the value(217976) for used memory

I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach using [Regex pattern capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7#groups-captures-and-substitutions):

```
$usedMemLine = vmstat -s | Select-String "(.+) . used memory"
$usedValue = $usedMemLine.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.  [Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split?view=powershell-7) it on whitespace, and pick the first resulting array element.

```
(-split $usedmem)[0]

217976
```

Comment: I tried this way, It is working as well  $usedstring = $usedmem.ToString().split()| where {$_} | select-object -first 1
PS /home/ec2-user> $usedstring
220980

Answer (score 0):

A better RegEx approach:

```
if($usedMem -match "^\s*(\d+).*"){$matches[1]}
```

Explanation:

```
^ Match characters at the beggining of string
\s Match a White space
* Match 0 or more instances of previous character
( Start grouping of specific match
\d Match a 0-9 digit
+ Match 1 or more instances of previous character
) End grouping of specific match
. Match any character
* Match 0 or more instances of previous character
```

`$matches[1]` returns the K value only, where `$matches[0]` will return the whole string.